# Nginx add_header header not capitalized

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I am running nginx in ubuntu 20.04

I'm trying to set `Cache-Control` header to `no-cache` as well as `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` to `*` in nginx.

Here is the configuration for my server location

```
location / {
  gunzip on;
  add_header 'Cache-Control' 'no-cache' always;
  add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' *;
  root /home/user/apps/client/wwwroot/;
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
}
```

But when I try to get the site in postman, I get the non-capitalized headers

`access-control-allow-origin` `*`
and
`cache-control` `no-cache`

As you can see they are not capitalized, I have tried to set the header name using `'Header-Name'` as well as `Header-Name`

The problem is that my Blazor WebAssembly app is not checking for a newer version of the static files in my server

Answer (score 0):

`HTTP` headers are case-insensitive and `HTTP/2` requires headers to be converted to lowercase. You need to check your application if it works with `Cache-Control` headers correctly.